# LIFO / sorted database design pattern

Tags: database, database-design, hbase

I want to store data (as an archive) in two seperate lists one is to be a sort of LIFO stack where new data just gets pushed on top and the other is sorted by a temporally independent value. Data may be retreived at a later point in time, but I'm generally only interested in the topmost N values. Both lists can get very long but contain very simple values (document ids with priority). Is there a database to implement this pattern efficiently? I hear HBase does sorted storage, would it be useful for this kind of application?

At least the LIFO storage could be implemented as a plain file. Is this wise?
Or is this concern about retreival speed premature optimization, i.e. are there commands in SQL with which i can retreive first N by time of insertion / sorted by a value . Or should I shard / paginate?

Comment: what is the number of records we're talking about ("very long")?

Comment: tens of thousands to tens of millions.

Answer (score 1):

Rows or "tuples" if you like, are specifically **not** ordered in a relational database. It is considered an implementation detail. Of course, we often need to impose an order of the rows anyway, but we have to do it when we query the data, not when we store it.

I have no knowledge of hbase, but I noticed it was free, so if you can consider MySQL an alternative, here is one way to do what you want.

Create an InnoDB table with an auto-incrementing primary key. InnoDB tables are clustered on the primary key, meaning that the rows are stored sorted by the key. Since you use an auto-incrementing key, newer rows will always have higher values, and rows added in sequence will be stored "near" each other. Those properties make for fast retreival of the X newest or oldest rows, since they will likely be co-located on the same data pages (reduces I/O).

It would be something like this:

```
create table mytab(
   id       int not null auto_increment
  ,the      int
  ,rest     varchar
  ,of       char
  ,your     tinyint
  ,columns  varchar
  ,primary key(id)
)Engine=InnoDB;
```

To get the 10 latest rows added, you would query it like:

```
select *
  from mytab
 order 
    by id desc
 limit 10;
```

Note that even if you are deleting the rows, the ID will keep on increasing. So if the MAX(id) is 5000, it doesn't mean you have 5000 rows.

Comment: realizing that order is not relevant at table level is crucial, let the RDBMS solve it.